# release date for next pysnmp package

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

Last released pysnmp 4.4.9 has dependency on pycrtyptodomex package. Current master branch seem to have removed this dependency. Can you please let me know when is the next version of pysnmp scheduled to be released? Also, I am assuming that it will not have pycryptodmex dependency

Ref: https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next pysnmp major release (5) will depend on `pysnmpcrypto` which relies on either `cryptography` or `pycryptodomex` depending on the Python version being used.

On top of that, even `pysnmpcrypto` dependency is weak meaning that pysnmp 5 works just fine without it for as long as no strong SNMPv3 crypto is involved.

The release date is anticipated to be around September 2019.